# How to set State variable for form Data

Tags: reactjs

I have an Form Data input in react js application. I have tried below code to set Form Data state variable but value is showing as empty. Please check below code and advise how to do this...

***Initial State :-***

```
this.state = {
  FormData: [{
    UserId: 0,
    FirstName: '',
    LastName: '',
    EmailId: '',
    MobileNo: '',
    DivisionId:'',
    UserName: '',
    Password: '',
    ConfirmPassword: '',
    RoleId: '',
    UpdateUserName: localStorage.getItem("UserId"),
    GridState: []
  }],
```

};

***Setting State Value in onchange event :-***

```
onChangeHandler = (event) => {
  let nam = event.target.name;
  let val = event.target.value;
  this.setState({[nam]: val});
}
```

***HTML render:-***

```
render() {
<div className="form-group row">
                  <label  className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">First Name</label>
                  <div className="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" name="FormData.FirstName" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtFirstName" placeholder="First Name" required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
                  </div>

                  <label  className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Last Name</label>
                  <div className="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" name="FormData.LastName" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtLastName" placeholder="Last Name" required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
                  </div>

                  <label  className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Email Id</label>
                  <div className="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="email" name ="FormData.EmailId" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtEmailId" placeholder="EmailId" required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
                  </div>

                </div>

                <div className="form-group row">
                  <label  className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Mobile No</label>
                  <div className="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" name ="FormData.MobileNo" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtMobileNo" placeholder="Mobile No" onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
                  </div>


                  <label  className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">User Name</label>
                  <div className="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" name ="FormData.UserName" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtUserName" placeholder="User Name" required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
                  </div>

                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group row">
                  <label  className="col-sm-1 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Password</label>
                  <div className="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="password" name ="FormData.Password" className="form-control form-control-sm" id="TxtPassword" placeholder="Password" required onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
                  </div>
```

***Please check submit button handling code :-***

```
onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.FormData));
  alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.FormData));

}
```

Comment: The problem doesn’t seem to be in the state but probably in the submission. Can you share the function handling the submission?

Comment: You update your state incorrectly. Either change it's shape to a flat object (this is how you treat it anyway) or change your state update to this shape (which in your case would look like `this.setState({FormData: [{...this.state.FormData[0] ,[nam]: val}]);` (approximatly) which does not make much sense in the first place

Comment: It is never a good idea to store system objects with strong references in the state (such as maps, sets, FormData and etc..). Save the data from your form as regular strings and build the FormData object before submitting it.

Comment: can you have an example code please ???

Answer (score 0):

The value of `name` in component's state and in HTML are not the same -:

In HTML it is -:

- FormData.UserId
- similarly for all other fields....

In JS it is only -:

- UserId
- similarly for all other fields....

`FormData` prefix is not there in state

you can do something like this -:

```
onChangeHandler = ({target: {name, value} }) => {
  name = name.split(".")[1];
  const FormData = {...this.state.FormData, [name]: value};
  this.setState(FormData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatten your state structure to be *just* the form fields

```
this.state = {
  userId : 0,
  firstName: '',
  lastName : '',
  emailId : '',
  mobileNo : '',
  divisionId :'',
  userName : '',
  password : '',
  confirmPassword : '',
  roleId : '',
  updateUserName : localStorage.getItem("UserId"),
  gridState : []
};
```

Leave `onChangeHandler` as-is since it handles a flat state structure already.

Update `onSubmitHandler` to stringify the state object representing the form fields

```
onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state));
  alert(JSON.stringify(this.state));
}
```

Update form field names to match that in state. Example:

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="firstName" // <-- should match key in state
  className="form-control form-control-sm"
  id="TxtFirstName"
  placeholder="First Name"
  required
  onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
/>
```

***Note:*** camelCased all keys/names by normal naming convention.